# RoR display records from table other than current users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

their is a table called Colors

@user = User.find(currentuser.id)

@user.colors, displays all the colors of current_user

but,

I want to fetch the colors of all other users apart from current user's

please, tell me what will be code like

I tried like, **@c = Color.find(:all)**, this displays all the records

Is there any condition to avoid current user records..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @colors = Color.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id != ?", current_user.id])

Assuming user_id is the foriegn_key field.

Comment: what is the relationship between Users and Colors?  This will only work if a Color :belongs_to a User.  It seems more likely to me that you want a :has_many_through relationship.